# Compile Boost form Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, clang

I want to compile Boost with clang for Visual Studio.

So after downloading (version 1.58) I ran the bootstrap.bat to produce the b2.exe.

what command line swtches can i use to compile Boost?
I tried to do the following:
Downoaded MinGW, and copied all include files to **D:\local\test\include**

```
set CPATH=D:\local\test\include
b2 toolset=clang architecture=x86 address-model=32 -j8
```

yet I get a zillion error messages saying "Sleep" is already defined blah, blah blah... Sleep is undefined blah, blah blah...

Comment: ***I tried to do the following: Downoaded MinGW, and copied all include files to D:\local\test\include*** Why did you do that?

Comment: are you using minGW or visual studio?  What version of visual studio?

Comment: Why do you want to use **clang** to compile for **Visual Studio**? How about using the prebuilt binaries available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.58.0/ ?

Comment: I am using VS2010. The command line I use s from the VS2010 tools->command prompt.

Comment: The reason I work with MinGW is because, I set CPATH to point to the include directory of VS, but then the (**CLANG**) compiler said that it did not recognize **`__w64`** so I reverted to MinGW. Here the cstddef couldn't find `#include <bits/c++config.h>` I located it in another _bits_ folder and so as not to contaminate the original MinGW include. I copied everything to a different folder

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually manage to compile it and I want to share the steps I took:

```
cd /d D:\local\boost_1_58_0\tools\build
bootstrap
cd ../..
"./tools/build/b2.exe" --build-dir=d:/local/boost/aatest toolset=clang --build-type=complete stage architecture=x86 address-model=32 -j8
```

and although I had ***many*** errors and messages. I did get some sort of a boost library for clang for eample I have the *libboost_atomic-clang-mt-1_58.lib* file and many more.